# Using EGREP to find a substring repeated 3 or moretimes in a string

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to find any string that repeats any 4 word substring 3 times or more, with no overlapping (the substrings cant overlap each other)

Something like this:

```
grep -E '([A-Za-z]{4})\1\1' test.txt
```

I know that this is wrong but I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong or how to use the string repeating feature.

I'm specifically interested in doing this using EGREP, not other ways.

Some examples:

fourfourfour would be okay
fourfourfourfour would not be okay

none of the substrings can overlap, so if I was searching for "hehe" in hehehehe it would return false as there is only two non overlapping matches.

Comment: An example would be better.

Comment: So the word bananabananabanana would work as "bana" is repeated 3x exactly.

Comment: did your grep supports `-P`?

Comment: Yes, but I want to try to do it using -E

Comment: What is a `4 word substring` ?

Comment: A 4 word substring can be any 4 characters, as long as they are repeated in the main string 3 times.

Comment: So you mean 4-character substring, not 4-word substring.

Comment: I believe this question badly needs some example matches and non-matches.

Comment: Added examples to clarify

Comment: is `testfourfourfour` a match or not? also `fourfourfourfour` have only 3 `ourf`s

Comment: Okay, what if I changed it to 3 or more times?

Comment: I think EXACT can be done in Perl, its worth a try using grep in Perl mode.

Comment: So after your latest edit, why does it still say "I know that it's wrong"?  You edited it to an expression which appears to fulfill your requirements.  (Add `.*` before each `\1` to allow other stuff between the matches, if that's your problem.)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a four chracter string then you could try the below grep command.

```
grep -oP '^(?:(?!\1).)*\K(.{4})(?=(?:(?!\1).)*\1(?:(?!\1).)*\1(?:(?!\1).)*$)' file
```

Comment: Have you tried this `^(?:(?!\1).)*(.{4})(?:(?!\1).)*\1(?:(?!\1).)*\1(?:(?!\1).)*$` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep -P '^(.*?(....))(?=(.*?\\2){2}(?!(.*\\2){3}).*'
```

The key here is using reluctant quantifiers to consume as little as possible before each abc then a negative look ahead to disallow more than 3.

Comment: There seems to be a paren missing after `{2}`

Answer (score 0):

I have to take back an earlier statement. Getting EXACTLY x-number of matches does
appear to work in Perl (and possibly PCRE types too).

It does this because in Perl, variables can exist as multiple types, and as such each
has a control state. One of the states is defined or not.

So capture buffers can be referenced before they are actually defined.

```
This might not apply to command line grep (even in Perl mode), but it might be worth a try.
```

Adding to @AvinashRaj's regex, it can be done like this. I tested it in Perl, works there:

```
 # ^(?:(?!\1).)*(.{4})(?:(?!\1).)*\1(?:(?!\1).)*\1(?:(?!\1).)*$

 ^ 
 (?:
      (?! \1 )
      . 
 )*
 ( .{4} )             # (1)
 (?:
      (?! \1 )
      . 
 )*
 \1 
 (?:
      (?! \1 )
      . 
 )*
 \1 
 (?:
      (?! \1 )
      . 
 )*
 $
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are requesting specifically a `grep -E` solution, and all of the earlier answers seem hellbent on using `grep -P`, here's one more.

```
grep -E '(....)\1\1' file
```

This looks for a group four arbitrary characters (including spaces) repeated three times, adjacent to each other.

If you want to restrict to non-whitespace characters, try this instead.

```
grep -E '([^[:space:]]{4})\1\1' file
```

This looks more complicated, but really isn't: we use `[^[:space:]]` instead of `.` and specify four repetitions with `{4}` just because it would really suck to have to write `[^[:space:]][^[:space:]][^[:space:]][^[:space:]]`.

If you want to relax the adjacency requirement and look for a four-charcter string occuring three times on the same input line with some other characters in between, try this instead.

```
grep -E '(....).*\1.*\1' file
```

The parentheses perform grouping, but also capturing; whatever the first set of parentheses matched will be available as `\1`.  You cannot just say `(....){3}` because that simply says four characters, followed by any other four, followed by any other four.

Comment: The OP edited the question after 3 answers have been posted. And you solution will fail to detect substring repeating **exactly** 3 times. It only detects substring repeating 3 times or more.

Comment: Then you'd need something like `grep 'three' | grep -v 'four'` if the only allowed tool is `grep -E`.

Comment: It's hard to glean specific's from OP's, sometimes exactly means 'at least' sometimes it doesn't. Just doesn't seem like the difference is meaningful, albeit more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It does need to repeat EXACTLY three times, no more, no less. I added some examples to clarify.

Comment: Yes, minimum would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-regex solution using `awk`:

```
awk '{s=substr($0, 1, 4); print ($0 == s s s)?"match":"no match"}'
```

**Testing:**

```
echo "fourfourfour" | awk '{s=substr($0, 1, 4); print ($0 == s s s)?"match":"no match"}'
match

echo "hehehehe" | awk '{s=substr($0, 1, 4); print ($0 == s s s)?"match":"no match"}'
no match
```